# Connecting to lampp mysql database using C on Linux

Tags: mysql, c, database, linux, lampp

I downloaded and installed XAMPP for linux latest ["Development package"](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374) from XAMPP website.
Now I want to connect to MySQL database with C and it seems `mysql.h` is not included in above package.
I followed instructions given in [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html) link. I installed `libmysqlclient15-dev` but an error message is given when a test program (example given in above second link) is run.

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

There is no `mysqld.sock` file in above location. But there is a `mysql.sock` file in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql` (this is where LAMPP is installed).

What should I do in order to connect with MySQL server that comes with LAMPP?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a symlink to where the file actually is, and tell us if it worked. If that's the problem, surely you can override the default path setting for that file.

How to create the symlink: This can be done by executing the following command in the terminal. Root user permissions are required: ln -s /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Yes that was the problem, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to `xampp` from the browser? If you can't, do the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Now you have an open default socket.